# Update field to zero in one table when data for the respective field is not present in the other table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite. There are two tables shown below.

```
Transaction_Tbl
ID    Name    Credit/Debit    Value
1     ABC        credit        10
1     ABC        credit        10
2     DEF        credit        20
2     DEF        debit         40
(record for third employee EFG not present in the table)
```

Based on the table, Emp_Tbl must be updated as below...

```
Emp_Table
ID    Name    Avg(Credit-Debit)
1     ABC     20
2     DEF     -20
3     EFG     0 (as no records for EFG in Transaction_Tbl)
```

Now if there is a record for EFG in Transaction_Tbl for Debit, then in Emp_Tbl, the record for EFG must be negative (credit - debit => where credit must be taken as zero as no records for credit.).

How to do it?

Comment: would all of the names be in the Average_Table or would you also be adding new names to Average_Table if they are in Transaction_Table?

Comment: Why is this called "average" when you actually want to compute the sum?

Comment: _“How to do it?”_ – what, you want the whole thing from us? What is your attempt at solving this?

Comment: @CBroe I have tried function IFNULL but no idea how to do it.

Comment: @Zohra Edited  question. And yes, all of the names in the Emp_Tbl.

Comment: @CL, what if the name was Abc-Tbl. The question would be the same.

Comment: @DhavalR: _“what if the name was Abc-Tbl”_ – this is not about the table name, but about the value that you want to calculate – and that is obviously a _sum_, not an _average_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a table `names` listing all names (else where would `efg` sprint out from?!), then something like...:

```
sqlite> create table trans (id smallint, name string, cord string, value int);
sqlite> insert into trans(id,name,cord,value) values(1,'abc','credit',10);
sqlite> insert into trans(id,name,cord,value) values(1,'abc','credit',10);
sqlite> insert into trans(id,name,cord,value) values(2,'def','credit',20);
sqlite> insert into trans(id,name,cord,value) values(2,'def','debit',40);
sqlite> select * from trans;
1|abc|credit|10
1|abc|credit|10
2|def|credit|20
2|def|debit|40
sqlite> create table names (name string);
sqlite> insert into names(name) values('abc');
sqlite> insert into names(name) values('def');
sqlite> insert into names(name) values('efg');
```

to create and populate the tables and check the main one, then

```
sqlite> select names.name, sum(case trans.cord when 'credit' then trans.value when 'debit' then -trans.value else 0 end) from names left outer join trans on names.name=trans.name group by names.name;
abc|20
def|-20
efg|0
```

seems roughly what you're after, right?